# Displaying textual representation of day using strtotime function in PHP

Tags: php

How to display the text representation of day like sunday monday to the desired date ... I am using the strtotime function to display the date, but how to add the text day side to the date below.

```
$r=27 July 2012;
echo $r;
$cmg = strtotime("$r");
$now = time(); //25 July 2012
$timeleft = $cmg-$now;
$daysleft = round((($timeleft/24)/60)/60); //probably...
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;There are $daysleft days left!";
```

This outputs a date

```
27 July 2012
There are 2days left !
```

Desired output is

```
27 July 2012 Friday
There are 2days left!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the date in this format `YYYY-MM-DD` then use the `Date()` function:

```php
$myDate = '2012-07-25';

echo date('l', strtotime($myDate));

//Friday
```

Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php